# What is wrong in my docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need a little bit of help to find why my docker-compose.yml doesn't work. The story is that I have a docker-compose.yml who works (and who create Grafana, Prometheus, nodeexporter, cAdvisor and alertManager) then I want to do one without Grafana so I just removed all the Grafana things of the file but it doesn't work.

the one who works :

```
version: '2'

networks:
  monitor-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
    prometheus_data: {}
    grafana_data: {}

services:

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '-config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '-storage.local.path=/prometheus'
      - '-alertmanager.url=http://alertmanager:9093'
      - '-storage.local.memory-chunks=100000'
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9090
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  alertmanager:
    image: prom/alertmanager
    container_name: alertmanager
    volumes: 
      - ./alertmanager/:/etc/alertmanager/
    command:
      - '-config.file=/etc/alertmanager/config.yml'
      - '-storage.path=/alertmanager'
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9093
    ports:
      - 9093:9093
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  nodeexporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter
    container_name: nodeexporter
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9100
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  cadvisor:
    image: google/cadvisor:v0.24.1
    container_name: cadvisor
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:rw
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 8080
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: grafana
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
    env_file:
      - user.config
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 3000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"
```

The one who doesn't work:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  monitor-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
    prometheus_data: {}

services:

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '-config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '-storage.local.path=/prometheus'
      - '-alertmanager.url=http://alertmanager:9093'
      - '-storage.local.memory-chunks=100000'
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9090
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  alertmanager:
    image: prom/alertmanager
    container_name: alertmanager
    volumes:
      - ./alertmanager/:/etc/alertmanager/
    command:
      - '-config.file=/etc/alertmanager/config.yml'
      - '-storage.path=/alertmanager'
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9093
    ports:
      - 9093:9093
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  nodeexporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter
    container_name: nodeexporter
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9100
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  cadvisor:
    image: google/cadvisor
    container_name: cadvisor
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:rw
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 8080
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"
```

With the second one the container Prometheus can't run and the logs are:

```
level=info msg="Starting prometheus (version=1.5.2, branch=master, revision=bd1182d29f462c39544f94cc822830e1c64cf55b)" source="main.go:75"
level=info msg="Build context (go=go1.7.5, user=root@1a01c5f68840, date=20170220-07:00:00)" source="main.go:76"
level=info msg="Loading configuration file /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml" source="main.go:248"
level=error msg="Error opening memory series storage: leveldb: manifest corrupted (field 'comparer'): missing [file=MANIFEST-000009]" source="main.go:182"
```

Comment: and "does not work" means exactly what?

Comment: @Henry it means that with the one who "works" every containers are running and with the one who "does not work" the container Prometheus can't run because the manifest is corrupt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that Prometheus at least starts and then errors out means that your compose files is probably correct.

It seems to at least try to load the configuration file `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml` and fails doing so.

In the compose file I see that it adds a host volume which is expected to exist on your host system at location `./prometheus/`. Did you also copy this folder and it's contents? If yes, did you verify that the configuration is correct and is expected to work without Grafana? Also it's important what your current directory is when you run docker-compose, it must be where the `./prometheus/` directory is located.

Comment: So thank you for your answer :) now I'll answer to yours, so yes I copy the folder and his content, the configurations files are the same as the one in the folder who contains the working yml. Yes when I run the `docker-compose` I'm in the directory of the yml file. I'll search if I can find something with the advices you gave me

Comment: Another thing you should check is the prometheus_data volume. I'm not sure how docker-compose internally names volumes and especially if the compose project name is prepended (as with containers). I did'd use compose for a while now and can't verify this atm. Please check what `docker volume ls` gives you and if you find the prometheus_data once or twice. If you find it only once, it means both your compose files share the same volume, probably resulting in errors. If you see two of them, try to delete the one that corresponds to the not working compose file and then retry starting prometheus.

Comment: I removed the volume then it created it again and now it works ! Thank you so much